# MPRIS integration with Python or VLC-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, python-vlc

Does anybody know of an easy module to interact with MPRIS and write metadata to it?
I'm trying to get a music player working with the OS, and I'm using VLC [`python-vlc`] as it's backend. If you can help me out find any module that allows me to easily write metadata, thanks.

Modules I've tried:

- `playerdo` - Only reads metadata
- `playerctl` - Only reads metadata
- `modipy-mpris` - Doesn't work
- `mpris-server` - Breaks constantly and generally a pain to set up
- `vidify` - Not what I've wanted

VLC docs: https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/index.html

**NOTE:** This is not what my player looks like, this is KDE's Applet allowing me to see what is playing. I'm sure windows has something similar, but the most important thing is I need to be able to play and pause music from anywhere in the OS with the play/pause button on my keyboard or bluetooth device

Example of output: [KDE Plasma Applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNFNh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MPRIS-SERVER but read [the issues](https://github.com/alexdelorenzo/mpris_server/issues/1#issuecomment-644402025).
Still a pain to set up but at least it works properly.